# Python seed (random.seed) is not giving replicable results

Tags: python, random

I want to create some code that uses both `random.sample` and `numpy.random.randint` but in such a way that is completely replicable.  How do I properly set the seed for `random.sample`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

np.random.seed(3)
random.seed(3)

numteam = 3

nameslist = {"Abigail", "Briana", "Charlotte", "Daisy", "Emma", "Florence", "Gail", "Heather", "Imogen", "Jane", "Kelly", "Mara", "Natalie", "Olivia", "Patricia"}
team = random.sample(nameslist, numteam)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(numteam, numteam)), columns = team)
df.index = team

print(df)
```

I ran this code twice on the same online compiler and get different name selections (the `randint`  is consistent)
[image]

Interestingly, if I use a different online compiler the seed seems to stick.  I need to be able to have others run the code using whatever compiler they like and get the exact same "random" data frame as what I have (each user will have a unique seed so no two people get the same data frame).

I've looked at a lot of examples online, but from what I can tell `random.seed` is what I am meant to be doing.  I am using Pycharm 2020.2 with Python 3.8 locally.  The two online compilers I have tried are https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php and https://pynative.com/online-python-code-editor-to-execute-python-code/

Comment: Sets are not intended to have a deterministic order. Stop using a set. (Sampling from a set has nasty efficiency problems too - `random.sample` never should have been designed to take sets in the first place.)

Comment: Why are you using a set in the first place? Did you get things mixed up with some other language that uses braces for arrays?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thank you.  Yes I have got my languages mixed up there, and since it was giving me the results I wanted (until I tried to replicate) I completely failed to notice I had that wrong.  As is probably obvious - I am not very good at this.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica What nasty efficiency problems?

Comment: @Manuel: It has to call `tuple` on the set every time, taking time proportional to the size of the whole set even if you only want a small sample.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, that. I thought maybe you meant something additional. Anyway, in 3.9 it's deprecated. [Issue leading to that](https://bugs.python.org/issue40325).